# Hue Installation Issue - Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, hue

I am trying to setup Hue on my Mac.

This is the GitHub link I referred to:
https://github.com/cloudera/hue#development-prerequisites

```
$ git clone https://github.com/cloudera/hue.git
$ cd hue
$ make apps
```

Getting this error:: when running build/env/bin/hue runserver

hue soundarya$ build/env/bin/hue runserver

```
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x108be1cf8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/soundarya/virtenv/hue_venv/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.7.egg/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 93, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/soundarya/virtenv/hue_venv/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 102, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/soundarya/virtenv/hue_venv/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 310, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Users/soundarya/virtenv/hue_venv/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/validation.py", line 34, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/Users/soundarya/virtenv/hue_venv/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/loading.py", line 196, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/Users/soundarya/virtenv/hue_venv/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/loading.py", line 78, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/Users/soundarya/virtenv/hue_venv/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/loading.py", line 99, in load_app
    models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
  File "/Users/soundarya/virtenv/hue_venv/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.7.egg/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/soundarya/virtenv/hue_venv/hue/apps/jobbrowser/src/jobbrowser/models.py", line 20, in <module>
    import lxml.html
  File "/Users/soundarya/virtenv/hue_venv/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml-3.3.6-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/soundarya/virtenv/hue_venv/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml-3.3.6-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/lxml/etree.so, 2): Library not loaded: libxml2.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/soundarya/virtenv/hue_venv/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml-3.3.6-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/lxml/etree.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: etree.so requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Maybe you need to install the Python development packages.  Just a guess though...

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisites are not yet satisfied. You have to install all the requirements listed here: [Development Prerequisites](https://github.com/cloudera/hue#development-prerequisites). To ged rid of this error, you have to install `python2.7-dev` package(not python2.7-devel) and also other requirements.

Comment: I already have python2.7 installed. but still getting same error.

Comment: @SoundaryaThiagarajan Not just python2.7. You need Python Development packages which is `python2.7-dev` or `python2.6-dev`. Have you installed them?

Comment: I do have python2.6 and python2.7 as well. is there any diff between dev or devel?

Comment: @SoundaryaThiagarajan No. There is no difference. Are you getting the same error?

Comment: Have updated the question with the error. Getting a different error now. Posted above in the question.

Comment: @SoundaryaThiagarajan Remove `config` file from `/Users/soundarya/Downloads/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/`.

Comment: @SoundaryaThiagarajan New error? Because we cannot discuss too many times in common, Let us move this discussion to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99935/discussion-between-soundarya-thiagarajan-and-mobin-ranjbar).